# Matlab get() function not correctly getting key pressed

Tags: matlab, simulation, game-physics

I am making a boat simulation based on the air boat design at:
https://github.com/cmontalvo251/MATLAB/tree/5002bcd426ab31fb882442e75eb3ad567b020a22/Boat

But when I run this script and press any of the arrow keys, the cursor jumps to the command window and is not input into the script.

```
function keypress(varargin)
global uk

%%%uk = [dt,dr];

key = get(gcbf,'CurrentKey');

switch key
    %%%Increase Thrust
 case 'uparrow'
  uk(1) = uk(1) + 1;
  if uk(1) > 100
      uk(1) = 100;
  end
  %%%%Decrease Thrust
 case 'downarrow'
  uk(1) = uk(1) - 1;
  if uk(1) < 0
      uk(1) = 0;
  end
  %%%%Turn Left? 
 case 'leftarrow'
  uk(2) = uk(2) + 0.1;
  if uk(2) > 30*pi/180
      uk(2) = 30*pi/180;
  end
  %%%%Turn Right?
 case 'rightarrow'
  uk(2) = uk(2) - 0.1;
  if uk(2) < -30*pi/180;
      uk(2) = -30*pi/180;
  end
end
```

Is this a problem with MatLab? I watched this video on how the script works but my simulation does not run the same.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NT9vEOMm6vM&ab_channel=MonteCarlos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems all I had to do was press enter in command window and reopen the graph. The simulation runs for 200 seconds, this can also be changed.